# Getting table data excluding constraints

Tags: mysql

Table1 - has constraints with Table2 & Table3

Table2

Table3

- Any data which is present in table1 with constraints with table 2 & 3 is valid data.
- There are some bogus data somehow entered in table1 by manually turning off the constraint.
- I want to collect those data which is present only in table1 without any constraints.

Is there an easy way to get table1 data in mysql which don't have constraint data attached to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking for missing or bogus records in the parent table. I'm going to imagine that the constraint field in table2 and table3 is `id` and the fk fields in table1 are `table2_id` and `table3_id`. If this is the case, you'd query for missing joins:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.table2_id, t1.table3_id FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.table3_id
WHERE t1.table2_id IS NULL
OR t1.table3_id IS NULL;
```